# Script to open terminal in Kali, create multiple new tabs, rename and colour code them

Tags: python, bash, terminal, zsh

I need help creating a script, bash, python whichever works best within Kali linux.

What I need the script to do is open up the default terminal (ZSH) create the following new tabs - main, msf, nc listener, http server, serachsploit and then colour code them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bash script to create the tabs. I am not sure about the colorcoding.

```
#!/bin/bash

mate-terminal --tab --title="main"
mate-terminal --tab --title="msf"
mate-terminal --tab --title="NC Listener"
mate-terminal --tab --title="http server"
mate-terminal --tab --title="Searchsploit"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for posting a reply, unfortunatly that doesnt work for me as im not using Mate Im using the xfce4 default termainl in the lastest Kali.

Comment: looks like this works as a command to pop a new terminal - exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a script:

```sh
sleep 1m;gnome-terminal –geometry=150×50 –tab –title="echo" -e "bash -c \"echo "hello";echo "there";exec bash\"" –tab –title="idea" -e "bash -c \"/opt/idea-IU-111.69/bin/idea.sh;exec bash\"" –tab –title="sql" -e "bash -c \"mysql -uroot -pigdefault;\"" –tab –title="firefox" -e "bash -c \"/usr/bin/firefox www.gmail.com;\""
```

The script above will open a terminal with 4 tabs:

1. echo "hello there"
2. Idea
3. MySql
4. Firefox

The script will also set the titles in the terminal for each tab.

One can personalize the above script accordingly.

Description of the script :

```sh
sleep 1m             : Executes the script after 1 minute so that the system finishes 
                       its startup process.
gnome-terminal       : Open a terminal.
  -geometry=150×50   : Set screen size for terminal.
  –tab               : Open new tab
  –title             : Set title for the terminal
  -e                 : Execute the argument inside the terminal.
exec bash            : Starts a new bash after executing all the commands. 
                       This command is required if you do not want to close the current tab.
```

2. Save the script anywhere in the file system and make the file executable using the following command:

```sh
$chmod +x file.sh
```

3. Add this file to startup applications :

Go to  System > Preferences > Startup Applications

Click on add and in "command" write:

```sh
bash path/to/your/file.sh
```

Close and its done!

Next time when you start your system, all the tasks mentioned in the script will be automated.

Comment: Thank you ill have a play around with this, ill need to amend it as my terminal is TerminalEmulator.